# How do I disable "cursor beyond end of line"?

Tags: delphi, ide, c++builder

How do I deactivate Delphi's "Cursor beyond end of line" feature? When I click in the empty space to the right of a line, or when I navigate to a line with the arrow keys, I want the cursor to be at the line's real end, not in the "virtual space".

Comment: Try pushing [End] if you wish your cursor to be at the end of the line. (I think this is why that button is captioned "End".)

Comment: Pushing [End] in a black line (not empty! I already inserted spaces to indent the code!) moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, not the end. So whenever I come back to the code, clicking into the line I want to add new code, I have to manually move the cursor to the correct position...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot.  The code editor has always had that behavior built-in.  You can tell it to not go past End-Of-File, but not End-Of-Line.

Comment: This is so annoying!  I can't believe this still isn't an option.  Both C Builder and Delphi are mind blowing tool assets, but such a simple thing keeps me using a different Editor and only using them for editing Forms.

Comment: @TylerB.Wear: ask Embarcadero. I guess not too many people, if any, ever complain about it, so they don't do anything about it.  If you really want it addressed, feel free to file a report with [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com) and get people to vote on it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau bunch of people complained about this "feature" throughout the years. Embarcadero did the usual: _NOTHING_.

Answer (score 1):

When possible you can set a macro on one of the mouse buttons to hit the combo "left-click" and "End" when clicked. Not the ideal situation but it does the trick.