# Delphi XE6 Code Editor

Tags: delphi, ide, settings, delphi-xe6, code-editor

When I click on the empty place in the code editor, cursor stands beyond the end of line. How can I configure so that the cursor was placed exactly at the end of the line?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge it isn't an available option. I found [this Yahoo Groups discussion](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/GExpertsDiscuss/conversations/topics/4101) and [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977490/embarcadero-rad-studio-cursor-beyond-end-of-line), but they apply to Delphi XE and XE4 respectively. I did some searching in my own copy, but couldn't find an option that changes this behaviour.

There has been an [open bug request](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=44430) for it since 2007 which was last updated in 2012, but I can't see any details concerning this being in development.

A possible solution to this issue is to use the <kbd>End</kbd> key on your keyboard after you select past the end of a line, which will move the cursor to the right hand side of the last character. Unfortunately, it's not an automated solution, but it's the one that I use until such an option is added.